git: commit amend created parallel commits
Using PHPStorm's interface, I committed five files and pushed to GitHub (I'm the only developer - I just use GitHub as a sort of backup). Then I realized a little more clean-up was needed on one of the files, so I did that and then tried to do a commit amend with push. But it refused the push, saying there were conflicts I would need to merge. Huh? I tried to follow its instructions, saying that indeed my local file is what I want. Then I did a force push. I think it worked, but I now have an ugly bit in my branch log, with two versions of the same commit split apart and then merged. How can I get it to just be a single, normal commit instead?
Clarification
In response to all the comments and even one answer explaining why this happened and how I messed up: I already know I messed up. The point of my question is to ask how to fix it - how to make the tree look as if I only did one commit. I thought that's what commit -amend was for, but apparently that's only true if I don't push or if I force-push.
Despite using Git for years and trying to understand, I never really got my head around how it works or how to use it beyond basic commits. Even branching and merging feel like voodoo.

"An ugly bit"? So the problem you want to solve is the discomfort you're feeling while seeing a graph you can't explain? I'd suggest reading a bit of literature on the subject to understand that your new commit and the old one have their parent in common, and that git is usefully showing to you the state of your commit tree.

Git's (or Github's) suggestions are geared towards a collaboration workflow. You are not collaborating with anyone. You should have just force-pushed the amended commit.

Amended git commits create entirely new commit hashes.  That's why if you push, then amend, git status will tell you that your repo and the remote have diverged.  https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history

When you tried to push the first time, Git refused and suggested to run git pull. Which you probably did. Everybody does this, but who knows what git pull does behind the scene? It is written in the documentation: "More precisely, git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and then depending on configuration options or command line flags, will call either git rebase or git merge to reconcile diverging branches." The default behaviour is to call git merge.

@j6t Yeah, I realize that now. At this point I'm just trying to clean it up to where it would have been had I force-pushed the amended commit (or had not committed in the first place until that file cleanup had been done). I just want one commit in the tree.

If you still don't understand Git (and from your surprise at what --amend does, it sounds like you don't), you might want to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/

@matt Thanks for that excellent article. I already knew most of it, but it connected some dots in my brain that were previously unconnected. But the article's --amend example  results in e676370 visible and 8fcb682 hidden (waiting for garbage collection), which is exactly what I expected. Instead, I got two commits with the first one on an unnamed branch by itself (that was then merged, because git told me I needed to do that). I assume it's either because I edited a file (not the commit message) or because I pushed after the first commit.

Amending a commit is a bit of a misnomer - once a commit is created, it can not be changed. What git commit --amend does is create a new commit on top of the parent of the commit you're "amending" with the committed content. As a nice UX helper, it will also offer the "old" commit's commit message as a starting point for the new one's, but again, that's just a UX improvement.
By definition, you'll now have two commits (the "old" and "new" one) branching out of the parent. You can always prune your repo to get rid of commits without branches, , but there's no way to avoid this branching.

I guess pruning is what I'm asking how to do then. I struggle to remember how to do anything in git beyond basic commits - I've used it for years but never got a handle on it.

Hmm, I tried reading https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune , but it assumes way more understanding than I have. "unpacked objects unreachable from any of these head objects"? I have no idea what most of those words mean in the git context.
